# WordPress jQuery scrollbar

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Do not refer me to use nice scroll WordPress plugin. (old version)

I visited http://buzztheme.net/ to report DMCA.
But I saw a custom jQuery scrollbar like of Gmail in their template.

I want to know how I can have it for my WordPress theme.
Any script out on the web. Or this is a WordPress plugin. 
Just any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just done with CSS and the `::webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background : blue;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dU6Mp/)

Comment: Thanks, Is this cross browser and works on mobile devices. and will it work horizontally. HNY

Comment: It works horizontally, but styling scroll bars is not cross browser, and this only works in webkit. The only cross browser solution is faking the scroll bars with javascript, but Google and the site you're linking to are using the webkit styles.

Comment: Is their a tutorial about javascript for wordpress?

Comment: There's the Wordpress Codex and the jQuery documentation, it's all very well documented on their pages, and even in Wordpress, it's still just javascript, so any book on javascript would help, but creating fake scrollbars is really complicated and generally have some issues, thats why almost noone uses it.

Comment: Thaks, Is there a wordpress plugin for style selector like http://theme-fusion.com/avada/ How do they develop style selector?